# Ansible playbook stuck in Task part without writing logs

Tags: linux, scripting, ansible, terraform

I'm writing an Ansible playbook to install prerequisites (Unzip, Python, Docker, Terraform) on a remote server. 
When running the playbook it passes all stages until it gets the "Install Terraform" part. In this stage, I'm running a script that installs Terraform on the server (the script works when it runs manually).
However, the playbook stuck in that stage without writing logs or failing.

The playbook called "Plans.yml" is:

```
---
- hosts: deploy_jnlp_servers
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: jenkins
  tasks:
    - name: Install Unzip
      apt:
        name=unzip
        state=latest

    - name: Install Python
      apt:
        name=python-pip
        state=latest

    - name: Install Docker
      pip:
        name=docker-py

    - name: Install Terraform
      script: /home/jenkins/Ansible/scripts/config_Terraform.sh

    - name: Validate Terraform
      shell: terraform version
```

The script called "config_Terraform.sh" is:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo apt-get update -y

# Install Unzip
sudo apt-get install unzip -y

# add addresses to /etc/hosts
echo "192.168.99.160 terraform.sample.com" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts

TERRAFORM_VERSION="0.12.21"
WORKDIR=/tmp/terraform
mkdir -p "$WORKDIR"
cd "$WORKDIR"

# Install Terraform
curl -f "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux$
sudo unzip terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -d /usr/local/bin/
sudo chmod +x  /usr/local/bin/terraform

# https://github.com/adammck/terraform-inventory
# Install terraform-inventory
wget https://github.com/adammck/terraform-inventory/releases/download/v0.8/terraform-inventory_v0.8_linux_a$
sudo unzip terraform-inventory_v0.8_linux_amd64.zip -d /usr/local/bin/
sudo chmod +x  /usr/local/bin/terraform-inventory

# https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/
#ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/vps-cloud.web-server.key -C "My web-server key"
cd ~
```

I'm attaching photos of the logs and the result of running the playbook.[image: Running the playbook]

[image: Running the playbook with "-vvv" option]

### ***EDIT:***

I've checked the ansible user ("jenkins" in my case) and validated that it has all the permissions on the remote server and also on the script I want to execute from the local ansible master server.
I've also changed to "become: false" in the YAML file, however, I still get errors. I've changed my script so now it only has 1 line of "sudo apt-get update".
When I run the playbook I'm getting the above errors:

> fatal: [jenkinsjnlpslave.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com]: FAILED! =>
>   {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 100, "stderr":
>   "Shared connection to jenkinsjnlpslave.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
>   closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to
>   jenkinsjnlpslave.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com closed."], "stdout":
>   "sudo: unable to resolve host JenkinsSlave-JNLP: Connection timed
>   out\r\n\r0% [Working]\r            \rIgn:1
>   http://debian-archive.trafficmanager.net/debian stretch
>   InRelease\r\n\r0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]\r
>   \rHit:2 http://debian-archive.trafficmanager.net/debian-security
>   stretch/updates InRelease\r\n\r0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for
>   headers]\r                                              \rHit:3
>   http://debian-archive.trafficmanager.net/debian stretch-updates
>   InRelease\r\n\r                                              \rHit:4
>   http://debian-archive.trafficmanager.net/debian stretch-backports
>   InRelease\r\n\r                                              \rGet:5
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu eoan InRelease [15.9
>   kB]\r\n\r                                              \r0% [5
>   InRelease 8260 B/15.9 kB 52%]\r
>   \rHit:6 http://debian-archive.trafficmanager.net/debian stretch
>   Release\r\n\r0% [5 InRelease 8260 B/15.9 kB 52%]\r0% [2 InRelease gpgv
>   94.3 kB] [5 InRelease 14.0 kB/15.9 kB 88%]\r0% [2 InRelease gpgv 94.3 kB] [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rGet:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease
>   [15.4 kB]\r\n\r
>   \r0% [2 InRelease gpgv 94.3 kB] [7 InRelease 8260 B/15.4 kB 54%]\r0%
>   [2 InRelease gpgv 94.3 kB] [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net
>   (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rHit:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch
>   InRelease\r\n\r
>   \r0% [2 InRelease gpgv 94.3 kB] [Waiting for headers]\r
>   \rIgn:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal
>   InRelease\r\n\r                                                   \r0%
>   [2 InRelease gpgv 94.3 kB]\r                             \rIgn:10
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal Release\r\n\r0% [2
>   InRelease gpgv 94.3 kB]\r                             \r0% [Waiting
>   for headers]\r0% [3 InRelease gpgv 91.0 kB] [Waiting for headers]\r
>   \rIgn:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main all
>   Packages\r\n\r                                                   \r0%
>   [3 InRelease gpgv 91.0 kB]\r                             \rIgn:12
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64
>   Packages\r\n\r0% [3 InRelease gpgv 91.0 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en\r\n\r0% [3 InRelease gpgv 91.0 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \r0% [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r0% [4 InRelease
>   gpgv 91.8 kB] [Waiting for headers]\r
>   \rIgn:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main all
>   Packages\r\n\r0% [4 InRelease gpgv 91.8 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   amd64 Packages\r\n\r0% [4 InRelease gpgv 91.8 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en\r\n\r0% [4 InRelease gpgv 91.8 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \r0% [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r0% [Release.gpg
>   gpgv 118 kB] [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main all
>   Packages\r\n\r0% [Release.gpg gpgv 118 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   amd64 Packages\r\n\r0% [Release.gpg gpgv 118 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \r0% [Waiting for headers]\r0% [5 InRelease gpgv 15.9 kB] [Waiting for
>   headers]\r                                                   \rIgn:13
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en\r\n\r0% [5 InRelease gpgv 15.9 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main all
>   Packages\r\n\r0% [5 InRelease gpgv 15.9 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   amd64 Packages\r\n\r0% [5 InRelease gpgv 15.9 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu eoan
>   InRelease\r\n\r
>   \r0% [Waiting for headers]\r0% [7 InRelease gpgv 15.4 kB] [Waiting for
>   headers]\r                                                   \rIgn:13
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en\r\n\r0% [7 InRelease gpgv 15.4 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main all
>   Packages\r\n\r0% [7 InRelease gpgv 15.4 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   amd64 Packages\r\n\r0% [7 InRelease gpgv 15.4 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu eoan
>   InRelease\r\n\r
>   \r0% [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r0% [8 InRelease
>   gpgv 44.8 kB] [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en\r\n\r0% [8 InRelease gpgv 44.8 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main all
>   Packages\r\n\r0% [8 InRelease gpgv 44.8 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \r19% [Waiting for headers]\r                         \rErr:12
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64
>   Packages\r\n  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]\r\n\r19%
>   [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]\r
>   \rIgn:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en\r\n\r
>   \r20% [Working]\r             \rFetched 31.2 kB in 0s (45.2
>   kB/s)\r\n\rReading package lists... 0%\r\rReading package lists...
>   0%\r\rReading package lists... 1%\r\rReading package lists...
>   51%\r\rReading package lists... 51%\r\rReading package lists...
>   85%\r\rReading package lists... 85%\r\rReading package lists...
>   89%\r\rReading package lists... 89%\r\rReading package lists...
>   91%\r\rReading package lists... 91%\r\rReading package lists...
>   91%\r\rReading package lists... 91%\r\rReading package lists...
>   91%\r\rReading package lists... 91%\r\rReading package lists...
>   96%\r\rReading package lists... 96%\r\rReading package lists...
>   99%\r\rReading package lists... 99%\r\rReading package lists...
>   99%\r\rReading package lists... 99%\r\rReading package lists...
>   99%\r\rReading package lists... 99%\r\rReading package lists...
>   99%\r\rReading package lists... 99%\r\rReading package lists...
>   Done\r\r\nW: The repository
>   'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not
>   have a Release file.\r\nN: Data from such a repository can't be
>   authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.\r\nN: See
>   apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
>   details.\r\nW: GPG error:
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu eoan InRelease: The
>   following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
>   not available: NO_PUBKEY 93C4A3FD7BB9C367\r\nW: The repository
>   'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu eoan InRelease' is
>   not signed.\r\nN: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated
>   and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.\r\nN: See apt-secure(8)
>   manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.\r\nW:
>   GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu eoan
>   InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the
>   public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB9B1D8886F44E2A\r\nW: The
>   repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu eoan
>   InRelease' is not signed.\r\nN: Data from such a repository can't be
>   authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.\r\nN: See
>   apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
>   details.\r\nE: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]\r\nE: Some index files failed to
>   download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.\r\n",
>   "stdout_lines": ["sudo: unable to resolve host JenkinsSlave-JNLP:
>   Connection timed out", "", "0% [Working]", "            ", "Ign:1
>   http://debian-archive.trafficmanager.net/debian stretch InRelease",
>   "", "0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]", "
>   ", "Hit:2 http://debian-archive.trafficmanager.net/debian-security
>   stretch/updates InRelease", "", "0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for
>   headers]", "                                              ", "Hit:3
>   http://debian-archive.trafficmanager.net/debian stretch-updates
>   InRelease", "", "                                              ",
>   "Hit:4 http://debian-archive.trafficmanager.net/debian
>   stretch-backports InRelease", "", "
>   ", "Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu eoan
>   InRelease [15.9 kB]", "", "
>   ", "0% [5 InRelease 8260 B/15.9 kB 52%]", "
>   ", "Hit:6 http://debian-archive.trafficmanager.net/debian stretch
>   Release", "", "0% [5 InRelease 8260 B/15.9 kB 52%]", "0% [2 InRelease
>   gpgv 94.3 kB] [5 InRelease 14.0 kB/15.9 kB 88%]", "0% [2 InRelease
>   gpgv 94.3 kB] [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease
>   [15.4 kB]", "", "
>   ", "0% [2 InRelease gpgv 94.3 kB] [7 InRelease 8260 B/15.4 kB 54%]",
>   "0% [2 InRelease gpgv 94.3 kB] [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net
>   (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Hit:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease",
>   "", "
>   ", "0% [2 InRelease gpgv 94.3 kB] [Waiting for headers]", "
>   ", "Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal
>   InRelease", "", "                                                   ",
>   "0% [2 InRelease gpgv 94.3 kB]", "                             ",
>   "Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal Release",
>   "", "0% [2 InRelease gpgv 94.3 kB]", "                             ",
>   "0% [Waiting for headers]", "0% [3 InRelease gpgv 91.0 kB] [Waiting
>   for headers]", "                                                   ",
>   "Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main all
>   Packages", "", "                                                   ",
>   "0% [3 InRelease gpgv 91.0 kB]", "                             ",
>   "Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64
>   Packages", "", "0% [3 InRelease gpgv 91.0 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en", "", "0% [3 InRelease gpgv 91.0 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "0% [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "0% [4
>   InRelease gpgv 91.8 kB] [Waiting for headers]", "
>   ", "Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   all Packages", "", "0% [4 InRelease gpgv 91.8 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   amd64 Packages", "", "0% [4 InRelease gpgv 91.8 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en", "", "0% [4 InRelease gpgv 91.8 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "0% [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "0%
>   [Release.gpg gpgv 118 kB] [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net
>   (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   all Packages", "", "0% [Release.gpg gpgv 118 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   amd64 Packages", "", "0% [Release.gpg gpgv 118 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "0% [Waiting for headers]", "0% [5 InRelease gpgv 15.9 kB] [Waiting
>   for headers]", "                                                   ",
>   "Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en", "", "0% [5 InRelease gpgv 15.9 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   all Packages", "", "0% [5 InRelease gpgv 15.9 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   amd64 Packages", "", "0% [5 InRelease gpgv 15.9 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu eoan
>   InRelease", "", "
>   ", "0% [Waiting for headers]", "0% [7 InRelease gpgv 15.4 kB] [Waiting
>   for headers]", "                                                   ",
>   "Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en", "", "0% [7 InRelease gpgv 15.4 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   all Packages", "", "0% [7 InRelease gpgv 15.4 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   amd64 Packages", "", "0% [7 InRelease gpgv 15.4 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu eoan
>   InRelease", "", "
>   ", "0% [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "0% [8
>   InRelease gpgv 44.8 kB] [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net
>   (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en", "", "0% [8 InRelease gpgv 44.8 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   all Packages", "", "0% [8 InRelease gpgv 44.8 kB] [Connecting to
>   ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "19% [Waiting for headers]", "                         ", "Err:12
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64
>   Packages", "  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]", "", "19%
>   [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]", "
>   ", "Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal/main
>   Translation-en", "", "
>   ", "20% [Working]", "             ", "Fetched 31.2 kB in 0s (45.2
>   kB/s)", "", "Reading package lists... 0%", "", "Reading package
>   lists... 0%", "", "Reading package lists... 1%", "", "Reading package
>   lists... 51%", "", "Reading package lists... 51%", "", "Reading
>   package lists... 85%", "", "Reading package lists... 85%", "",
>   "Reading package lists... 89%", "", "Reading package lists... 89%",
>   "", "Reading package lists... 91%", "", "Reading package lists...
>   91%", "", "Reading package lists... 91%", "", "Reading package
>   lists... 91%", "", "Reading package lists... 91%", "", "Reading
>   package lists... 91%", "", "Reading package lists... 96%", "",
>   "Reading package lists... 96%", "", "Reading package lists... 99%",
>   "", "Reading package lists... 99%", "", "Reading package lists...
>   99%", "", "Reading package lists... 99%", "", "Reading package
>   lists... 99%", "", "Reading package lists... 99%", "", "Reading
>   package lists... 99%", "", "Reading package lists... 99%", "",
>   "Reading package lists... Done", "", "W: The repository
>   'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not
>   have a Release file.", "N: Data from such a repository can't be
>   authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.", "N: See
>   apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
>   details.", "W: GPG error:
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu eoan InRelease: The
>   following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
>   not available: NO_PUBKEY 93C4A3FD7BB9C367", "W: The repository
>   'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu eoan InRelease' is
>   not signed.", "N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated
>   and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.", "N: See apt-secure(8)
>   manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.", "W:
>   GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu eoan
>   InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the
>   public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB9B1D8886F44E2A", "W: The
>   repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu eoan
>   InRelease' is not signed.", "N: Data from such a repository can't be
>   authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.", "N: See
>   apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
>   details.", "E: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]", "E: Some index files failed to
>   download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."]}

I've also tried with "expect" command (and installed pexpect). Still got errors (different ones):
[image: Errors after running the playbook with "expect"]

Comment: When you say "The script runs separately", do you mean it runs if you run it manually or when you run it as a separate playbook?

Comment: I meant running the script manually.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that the user which is running your script through Ansible (the ansible_user) does not have permissions to execute the sudo commands in your script. That's why when you run it manually, it works fine.

You can try adding become: yes. [Here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) you can find more information about it.

Good luck!

EDIT: `become: false` or the `expect` module should be used as playbook is already running with `become: yes`

Comment: The playbook is already running with `become: yes` but I think you're correct here and that the script is waiting for a sudo password prompt for the root user. Stripping the `sudo` from the script or running the `script` task with `become: false` should fix it.

Comment: I've checked the ansible user ("jenkins" in my case) and validated that it has all the permissions on the remote server and also on the script I want to execute from the local ansible master server.
I've also changed to "become: false" in the YAML file, however, I still get errors. I've changed my script so now it only has 1 line of "sudo apt-get update".
When I run the playbook I'm getting errors.

Comment: Have you tried adding a become_pass? Also, you can try using the expect module to answer the password prompt.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately still got the same errors as I mentioned in my edited post.

Comment: Well in that case you can try `--ask-sudo-pass`. If you can't be bothered entering the password you can try passwordless sudo but I advice against that.